# html+css usemap doesn't work

Tags: html, css, reference, slider

I want to do a slider that it's each image have and reference. Slider works, but reference showed only 5th reference. I don't know what I would do =(

Here's what I have so far:

```
<map name="rfr-ma">
    <area shape="rect" coords="0,0,640,320" href="ma.html">
</map>
<map name="rfr-jj">
    <area shape="rect" coords="0,0,640,320" href="jj.html">
</map>
<map name="rfr-kn">
    <area shape="rect" coords="0,0,640,320" href="kn.html">
</map>
<map name="rfr-aj">
    <area shape="rect" coords="0,0,640,320" href="aj.html">
</map>
<map name="rfr-bk">
    <area shape="rect" coords="0,0,640,320" href="bk.html">
</map>

<!-- Sildes -->

<img id="one" src="img/ma.jpg"  usemap="#rfr-ma"/>
<img id="two" src="img/kn.jpg" usemap="#rfr-kn"/>
<img id="three" src="img/aj.jpg" usemap="#rfr-aj"/>
<img id="four" src="img/bk.jpg" usemap="#rfr-bk"/>
<img id="five" src="img/jj.jpg" usemap="#rfr-jj"/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your coords are overlapping i.e., pointing to the same location: coords="0,0,640,320"
Change it to different locations for each link.

Comment: I did it especially, because I can't construct other way to solving my problem. Now I think how to solve this with js? Can you help?